# reading and writing cfg files in python

Tags: python, file, parsing, configuration

I am trying to read and write cfg files in python.
I've tried the package called configparser but it complains about missing headers because apparently it does not understand the format of my file.
I would like to know your opinion on this to accomplish this as easily as possible. Note: I need to stick with this format.

Here is the format of my file:

```
PROFILE_PERIODS =
(    // note that this is not a curly brace
        {       //comment
                PRIORITY = 1;
        },

        {       //comment
                DESCRIPTION = "drgdfth";
        }
)
TIME_SYNCHRONIZATION =
{
        INTERVAL = 100;
}
```

This config file is also read by a c library called libconfig.
Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://github.com/cnangel/python-libconfig)?

Comment: or maybe [this](http://code.google.com/p/pylibconfig/)

Comment: Do you have control over the configuration file format? If so, you maybe don't have to invent yet-an-other-configuration-file-format™ In that case, since your format is quite close to [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), with some minor adjustments you might use the [corresponding standard Python library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think the first link (python-libconfig) is very promising. I tried to install it and got no errors with make and make install. But then when I try to import it in python (from pylibconfig import Config) it says that the module is not found. Does any one have a suggestion. I need to figure out how to install it - preferably how to install it in a virtualenv. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file looks like it has [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html) format, which is reasonably common in the C/C++ world.

I've written [python-libconf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libconf), a pure-Python libconfig file reader/writer. The interface is borrowed from the `json` standard library module. It's pretty simple:

```
import libconf
with io.open('file.cfg', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    cfg = libconf.load(f)
```

It can be installed easily via pip (`pip install libconf`) and works well in virtual environments. Compared to other Python libconfig readers, it is both permissively licensed (MIT) and pure-Python (no C modules to compile).

Comment: I have not tried it, but thanks for implementing it. Seems to be the solution.

Comment: I am able to read using libconf, but how to write in cfg file using libconf ? any example ?

Comment: @SaurabhSengar: You can use ``libconf.dump()`` and ``libconf.dumps()``. The first writes to a file object, the second produces a string. The interface is  quite analogous to the ``json`` module.